# Give filenames of files containing given date time range

Tags: logging, analysis

I have a bunch of files in different sub folders within a folder on Linux . Each sub folder contains a bunch of files. Each file contains thousands of records  .Each record contains timestamp in format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm". I want the name of files which contains records having timestamp  within a specified datetime range provided as input i.e for every minute within the given range and not just start and end . It should be fast as it should search tens of files having thousands of records

Used different things but couldnt crack this